Connectedness implies equivariance
In theorem 6.7.2 in the note Moduli and Stacks by J.Alper, we are given the following:
Let $X,U$ be algebraic spaces of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $G$ be a connected affine algebraic group acting on $X,U$.
The author claims that if $U \longrightarrow X$ is an étale $G$-equivariant morphism, then $U^G = U \times_X X^G$ (where $(-)^G$ denotes the functor of fixed points). The proof goes as follows: we need to show that for any $S \longrightarrow U$ with $S \longrightarrow U \longrightarrow X$ equivariant, then $S \longrightarrow U$ itself is equivariant. By base change $U \longrightarrow X$ along $S \longrightarrow X$, we obtain an equivariant morphism $U_S \longrightarrow S$ and therefore we prove $U_S \longrightarrow S$ is equivariant instead. It admits a section $j \colon S \longrightarrow U_S$, which is open since $U \longrightarrow X$ is etale.
Here is the point that confuses me: since $G$ is connected, any orbit $Gj(s)$ with $s \in S$ is connected and hence contained in $S$. Can anybody explain this point?

The claim that $U^G = U \times_X X^G$ is definitely incorrect. For instance, assume that $X$ is a point (with the trivial $G$-action), then the natural morphism $U \to X$ is equivariant (for any $G$-action on $U$), but the LHS is $U^G$, while the RHS is $U$.

Sorry, the assumption is $U \to X$ is étale.
